# Sharepoint list, Display a link

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula

How can I display a hyperlink within a Sharepoint list  "please follow this link: https:"

This is just for sharepoint list, no 3rd party apps or infopath, also I'm not very technical so please include the formula (if needed for a calculated column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to insert a hyperlink in sharepoint list the column should be a rich text column or enhanced rich column.

If your column is existing column you can go to List setting>and column setting and change it to Rich text column
[image]

if you are creating new column in a list make sure the setting same as the picture.
[image]

if you have these setting when ever you whan to edit that column you will have the following editor which allows you to create link.

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry it's not this, I was talking about creating a column that in its default, would display a hyperlink, not how to create a form that accepts a hyperlink input